# Is there any way that I can lock excel cell if it has value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel

Is there any way to lock the excel cell if it has value and unlock it if it has no value contained?

e.g. if Persone updates the excel-sheet and sends it to another person, the second person only allows the update blank cells.

Comment: Best way would be locking all cells with values using a macro **before** sending it to another person. You'll need to execute it once before sharing the file

Answer (score 1):

LEt's say your data is they grey zone in the image below:

[image]

You want to lock all grey cells with values and keep unlocked the empty white cells. Manually, you can do it like this:

1. Select all grey zone (your whole dataset)
2. Right click--> Format Cells
   [image]
3. A dialog box appears. Go to tab **protect** and make sure checkbox *locked* is checked!
   [image]
4. Close dialog box
5. Select **again** all grey zone (your whole dataset)
6. In the upper option ribbon, go to tab Start and search for option Find & Select and then [Go to Special](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-select-cells-that-meet-specific-conditions-2d686424-6150-4015-a8e4-a5990f4d7e3a)

[image]

7. Select option [Blank Cells](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1065-excel-select-empty-cells.html)

[image]

8. Now repeat steps 2 to 4 but selection option *unlocked* in step 3

Now your empty cells are unlocked and nonempty cells are locked. Make sure you [protect the sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) (or the workbook) with a password **or the locking won't work!**

And yes, you can code this easily on a macro.

**UPDATE:** As far as I know, all cells are locked by default in Excel so probably you don't need steps 1-4 but just in case I've added them. But I'm pretty sure you can just select all blank cells and unlocked them and then setting a password.

Answer (score 0):

This little sub is placed in the sheet you want it to work on.
[image]

Every time a cell is changed, if the cell ends up with a value in it, then it will lock that cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Target.Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Target.Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If
End Sub
```

It does mean you can enter values into a cell exactly once, and then you have to unprotect the sheet to delete the values entered.  not exactly the solution you are after I fear...

Comment: *It does mean you can enter values into a cell exactly once* I think this solution is too rough because it makes the user able to type in **any** cell just once, so if the user fails before sending it, it cannot be undone unless manually unblocking and blocking.